# Memory footprint profiling

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, valgrind, memory-footprint

Suppose I have a program written in C/C++ and I'd like to find out how much of memory was used for data (heap, stack) and how much of memory was used for code (libs, executable files, etc).

I have once measured the dynamic memory space used using 'valgrind' but I don't think is has a feature to profile memory footprint for data and code.

Platform : Mac (possibly Linux)

Comment: Anything to do this is likely to be fairly platform specific, so you'll probably need to tell us the platform to get good answers.

Comment: Do you mean use of physical memory? Or use of virtual memory? (For example, if you memory map a 1GB file but don't touch the mapping, did you just use 1GB of memory or not?)

Comment: @Carsten, do you know if 'valgrind' can profile memory footprint for code? not for the memory footprint for data.. I am not asking if I can do some memory leaking check...

Comment: @Carsten OP is asking "How do I use Valgrind (or some other tool) to profile how much memory is consumed by heap versus how much is consumed by code segment?"

Comment: I have one fairly naive thought.  Make a small modification to the `main` routine of your program.  Declare a variable to be `volatile int stopAndHold = 1;` and then have a `while(stopAndHold) {}` loop at the beginning of your `main` routine.  Start the program, and use a process viewer to look at the amount of memory that the program is consuming.  This should give you an estimate of the size of the code, static data, and variables that main allocates on the stack.

Comment: @LCYSoft,Crashworks: sorry, I read it wrong. Deleted my post (because it was stupid :) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your development environment should have some sort of linker options.   Generally in such you can instruct it to create a link map.   The information you are looking for is likely to be in the link map, or calculable based on the information in the link map.